# How to print from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-3.6, user-defined-functions

```
def hello(name):
    name = ["John", "Marius", "Gica"]
    print(name)

hello(name)
```

When I hit run it hit me with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tdr/Desktop/run.py", line 11, in <module>
    hello(name)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Why can`t I print it?

Answer (score 4):

When you call `hello(name)`, `name` needs to be a variable defined somewhere else in your code. Just look at the error you're getting:

```
hello(name)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Python is looking around trying to see what `name` means. But it can't find a definition, so it produces that error. You need to either call the function with a specific value, for example the following would work:

```
hello("John")
```

Or you'd call the function with a variable that's already defined somewhere else. So the following would also work:

```
myName = "Ismael"
hello(myName)
```

---

If you don't intend to use the parameters inside the function, then it makes more sense to make the function take no arguments:

```
def hello():
    ... code here ...
```

If you want to select an item from a list at random you can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

def hello():
    name = ["John", "Marius", "Gica"]
    chosenName = random.choice(name) # this chooses a random name from the list
    print( chosenName )

hello()
```

---

**Printing the name passed as an argument, unless it's `None`** or empty

```
def hello(name):
    if name is None or name is "":
        print("Hello, World!")
    else:
        print("Hello, " + name + "!")

hello("")     # Hello, World!
hello("John") # Hello, John!
```

If you want to make the above solution a bit more elegant, you could write `if not name:` instead of `if name is None or name is ""`, since empty strings are falsy in Python.

Comment: and please tell me what does import random stands for ? can it work without it ?

Comment: actually i intend to make a function using the argument, that takes one string argument and returns Hello, <name>!

Comment: `random` is a library that we import to make use of `random.choice()`. This is the normal way to select a random item from a sequence, and this specific solution would not work without it. You can read more about `random` [https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice](here in the documentation).

Comment: and If name is empty or None, return Hello, World!

Comment: If you want to print the function received as  a parameter, make a function that takes an argument (`def hello(name)`). Check if `name` is none (`if name is None:`), and then print either `Hello, World` or the name passed as an argument (`print("Hello, " + name)`).